# What error code should a GA-Z87X-UD3H motherboard display when no CPU is inserted?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

To help me diagnose if my motherboards are defective, could someone please tell me what error code a GA-Z87X-UD3H motherboard should display when no CPU is inserted?

Built a new PC which worked for 20 minutes before crashing. Got motherboard replaced thinking that was the issue, it wasn't. Both motherboards continually boot and switch between primary and backup BIOS every few seconds. Regardless of CPU being present, different PSUs, all connections removed, inside or outside the case, memory changed or removed.

The interesting part is that I never get an error code on the debug LED display or any beeps, no matter what I change.

To help me diagnose if my motherboards are defective, could someone please tell me what error code a GA-Z87X-UD3H motherboard should display when no CPU is inserted?

Comment: Does it beep? And in reference to "Both motherboards continually boot and switch between primary and backup BIOS every few seconds. Regardless of CPU being present, different PSUs, all connections removed, inside or outside the case, memory changed or removed."....  You've removed the LED, power and reset connections as well and it continues to boot without you doing anything?  You've also removed the CPU and RAM and it still boots into a BIOS then reboots?  Something is fishy.  Motherboards don't usually post without CPU and RAM.  Please update your question or throw that board away.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. 
I had an Asus motherboard (P8P67 Pro) that after 2.5 years working fine, one day wouldn't start indicating an error with the CPU (CPU_Led). After testing and narrowing it down to either CPU/Motherboard, the Tech guy at the store told me it was likely motherboard as "he has never seen a CPU fail before"

So I buy a replacement motherboard, Gigabyte Z77X-UDH3. Bring it home tonight, hook it up and and install all the components and when I power on I'm seeing the exact behaviour you describe - powers on with fans for 1-2 seconds then turns off with no debug led code, no sounds nor display.. Few seconds later powers itself on again for 1-2 seconds then off, each time switching from m_bios led to b_bios led, master and backup...

After reading your post on Toms:
http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1770700/z87x-ud3h-power-loop-error-code.html
I'm thinking it's my CPU, but I haven't got another rig to test the CPU with.
Hoping to get an RMA with Intel.. Sigh, I need my pc, pain in the backside.

Answer (score 0):

CPU error should generate 6 short beep on Gigabyte.

If you don't hear the beep then the Power supply unit could be faulty.
Take a multimeter and check the voltage on the motherboard cable using pin out and verify the output voltage match the list.